# Fear of FaceTime scam

Tags: facetime

I was dealing someone about a rental property. They said they would call me on FaceTime. I was suspicious but went ahead with it anyway. When they called they immediately hung up and then (regretfully) I called back. No answer. Then I texted them and they said the rental wasn’t available any more.

Is making or receiving a FaceTime call a security risk?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  One question per question, please. Do you use FaceTime on watch or Mac or iPad?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any FaceTime vulnerabilities that you would need to be worried about.

Sounds like your biggest concern is a sketchy/unreliable realtor/property owner. Unfortunately there is no technology that I'm aware of that can protect you against them either.